# DataBinding: 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' does not contain a property with the name 'fileName'

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, visual-studio, data-binding

I am currently having trouble with data binding. I am still learning on how to have a correct way to make data binding. The problem is DataBinding: 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' does not contain a property with the name 'fileName'.

As far as I understand, the data binding is the fileName that need to be tally with the back end coding but although I made it the same, the error still occur. Below is my aspx.cs coding.

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        //byte[] bytes;
        string fileName;
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Ulysses"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 10 OLE_LINK_FILE_NAME FROM OLE_LINK";
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    sdr.Read();
                    fileName = sdr["OLE_LINK_FILE_NAME"].ToString();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;

        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        //Response.ContentType = contentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        //Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Here is my HTML coding:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000"
AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OLE_LINK_FILE_NAME" HeaderText="File Name"/>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign = "Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="DownloadFile"
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("fileName") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

From the coding, where actually did I miss with the parameter fileName?

Comment: Error is coming on load or after clicking download?

Comment: the page even cannot be displayed. It will automatically show the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data source you are setting for `GridView1`, is List of `System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal` and I think your class `System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal` either don't have property with the name `fileName` or it's scope is limited. If it exist, try to make it `public`.

from your comment below. You should replace `fileName` by `OLE_LINK_FILE_NAME` in command argument of download link.

Comment: I am not very familiar with C# but I do think your answer is the right one because Visual studio display that my error would be about System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal.

Where do I change it because I cant see it in my aspx.cs page.

Comment: Write System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal anywhere in .cs file and press F12 it will take you to class definition. One question, it is inbuild class or someone wrote it?

Comment: Question2: Can to describe the structure you are binding to grid?

Comment: The coding is from this link : http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-and-Download-files-from-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASPNet.aspx

I use it to learn on how to download files from database. I am not sure about the structure but basically i want to bind the data for a table in the database so that it can be downloadable at the webpage. I hope my explanation is enough.

Comment: OK. What are your data table columns in database, same as in link?

Comment: No its not the same. I want to get OLE_LINK_FILE_NAME from OLE_LINK table. You can see it as my download function. I have use the variable fileName to assign the value but still the error came out.